# htaccess prepend path only if url matches

Tags: .htaccess

This is what I am trying to do:

The old path for a specific category:

```
`https://mywebsite.com/tag/something/somethingelse`
```

The new path only if the request is for https://mywebsite.com/tag

```
https://mywebsite.com/options/tag/something/somethingelse
```

This is only if the requested url has /tag and does not have /options/tag. 
If the request is for protocol/domainname/tag without /options/ preceding /tag then we need to prepend it there.

As an example,need to redirect from this:

`https://myseniorchoices.com/tags/facilityamenitiesskillednursing/tv-room`

to this:

`https://myseniorchoices.com/options/tag/facilityamenitiesskillednursing/tv-room`

The "facilityamenitiesskillednursing/tv-room" is only an example, there are thousands of possibilities so it needs to be dynamic past the tag/

Please note also the plural "tags" turns into singular "tag", should that make a  difference.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [ask] and provide us with an [mcve] (the relevant part of your `.htaccess` file).

Comment: I have expanded with examples.

Answer (score 0):

To go from your first provided link to your second use a RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^tag/something/somethingelse$ /options/tag/something/somethingelse?&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Comment: This did not work for me, but thank you for your input

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was pretty straight forward, should have thought of it earlier. This worked for me:
RedirectMatch permanent tags(.*) https://myseniorchoices.com/options/tag$1